# Geometry and algebra stacked

Tags: calculus

A triangle $PQR$ has a point $A$ which lies either inside or on the given triangle. Let $f(x,y)= ax+by+c$.
Prove that
$f(A) \le max${$f(P),f(Q),f(R)$}. Can it be solved using linear programming?

Comment: I guess it can be because the objective is linear and so are the constraints and hence the problem basically reduces to a linear programming.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but a direct proof could run as follows:

For there to be a local extremum inside the triangle, we would need $$\nabla f=(a,b)=(0,0)$$ which only happens if $f(x,y)=0x+0y+c=c$, in which case $f$ is constant and clearly the claim holds.

Otherwise, we can restrict our attention to the boundary. Along a line parameterized as $\mathbf{x}(t)=(x_0,y_0)+t(u,v)$ we have $$f(\mathbf{x}(t))=(au+bv)t+(ax_0+by_0+c)$$ which is clearly either *constant* or monotone (depending on the coefficient of $t$). Either way, it is clear that extrema will occur only at the boundary points on the boundary curve, that is, at the vertices of the triangle.

Hence the global maximum of the compact region (which exists by EVT) must be, in this case, at one of the endpoints of the triangle. Therefore it follows that for any other point $A$ in the region, $$f(A)\le \max\{f(P),f(Q),f(R)\}.$$